# Sending array data in wordpress form

Tags: php, wordpress, gravity-forms-plugin

I am sending data from a wordpress form in one site to another third party website.
When I print_r() the array data on the wordpress form , it displays

```
Array ( 
[comp_title] => Test incident title 
[comp_desc ] => Officers reported are: first fname officer first lname officer , second fname officer second lname officer , third fname officer third lname officerLocation: locationDescription: desc 
[fullname] => Test reporter fnameTest reporter lname 
[email] => testemail@testreporter.co.ke [phonno] => 0700123456 
[anonymous] => 0 
[fac_id] => 24576 
)
```

However, on the third party site, when I use var_dump($_GET), it displays array(0).

This is php code from the wordpress site:

```
add_action("gform_after_submission_1", "set_post_content", 10, 2);
function set_post_content($entry, $form){

//set POST variables
$post_url= 'http://example.com/form_api.php';

$body= array(
'comp_title' =>     urlencode($entry['1']),
'comp_desc' =>     urlencode('Officers reported are: '.$entry['4.3'].' '.$entry['4.6'].' , '.$entry['14.3'].' '.$entry['14.6'].' , '.$entry['13.3'].' '.$entry['13.6'].'. Location: '.$entry['5'].'. Description: '.$entry['6']),
'fullname' =>  urlencode($entry['8.3'].' '.$entry['8.6']),  
'email' =>     urlencode($entry['10']),
'phonno' =>    urlencode($entry['9']),
'anonymous' => urlencode(0),
'fac_id' =>    urlencode(24576)
);

 $fields_string = http_build_query($body);

//open connection
$ch = curl_init();

//set the url, number of POST vars, POST data
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_URL, $post_url);
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_POST, count($body));
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $fields_string);

$result = curl_exec($ch);

curl_close($ch);

}
```

Then on form_api.php on the third party application i have:

```
$fac_id =  mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['fac_id']);
$comp_title = mysql_real_escape_string(strtoupper($_GET['comp_title']));
$comp_desc = mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['comp_desc']);
$fullname =mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['fullname']);
$email = mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['email']);
$phonno = mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['phonno']);
```

What could i be doing wrong?

Comment: You should work with $_POST superglobal I think, not $_GET.

Comment: Sure, works well now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're trying to grab `GET` data, but you are sending the request via `POST`.  Try grabbing `$_POST['fac_id']` instead of `$_GET['fac_id']`.

Comment: I can't believe i have been debugging this a whole day yet it was this simple. Thank you.

Comment: You're welcome, man!  Sometimes it just takes a second pair of eyes.